# why does ascii value vary for signed and unsigned character in c++?

Tags: c++

I have tried these 2 following codes:

```
    int main()
{
int val=-125;
char code=val;
cout<<"\t"<<code<<" "<<(int)code;
getch();
}
```

The output i got is a^ -125

The second code is:

```
    int main()
{
int val=-125;
unsigned char code=val;
cout<<"\t"<<code<<" "<<(int)code;
getch();
}
```

The output i got is: a^ 131

after trying both the codes is it safe to conclude that a character can have 2 ASCII values or my approach to find ASCII value(s) is flawed?

P.S.-
I was unable to upload the pictures of my output, so I am forced to type the output where the character I got isn't present in the standard keyboard.

Comment: Neither 131 nor -125 is ASCII. ASCII is 7 bit (0..127).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both examples 'code' has the same bitwise value. The first bit is 1, because it was a negativ number. Since both 'codes' have the same value the output character is the same (converting from number->character treats the number as an unsigned value).

After that you convert your character back to a (signed) interger. This conversion respects the type and the sign of you char.

->unsigned char -> int -> int always positiv

->char -> int -> int has the same sign as the char (and because the first bit was 1 it's negativ here)

Comment: re "In both examples 'code' has the same bitwise value", only with two's complement representation of signed integers. Note that the representation is not indicated by the OP's results. Conversion to unsigned is well defined and depends only on the logical value, not the particular representation (C and C++ allow two's complement, one's complement and sign-and-magnitude representations of integers).

Answer (score -1):

unsigned integers in C++ have modulo 2<sup>n</sup> behavior, where n is the number of value bits.

that means if your `char` has 8 bits, then `unsigned char` has modulo 256 behavior.

<sup>this behavior is as if the values 0 through 255 were placed on a clockface. any operation that produces a result that goes past the 0-255 divide just effectively wraps around. just like arithmetic with hours on a clockface.</sup>

which means that assigning the value `-125` yields the corresponding value in the range 0 through 255, namely -125 + 256 = 131.